# Babel --watch flag is not transpiling my JSX code in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am working with React and am following a tutorial and am having an issue with the transpiling of my JSX code. When I run the babel command with the --watch flag, the page updates itself one time, but if I make a 2nd change, the live-server recognizes the change but babel does not update the view. Any idea why babel won't transpile more than once? I am running this project on Ubuntu 19.04.

Current project.

```
In Root:
node_modules (installed with yarn)
public/index.html
public/scrips/app.js
src/app.js
package.json
yarn.lock
```

I am using my src/app.js file to write my JSX and my scripts/app.js as my output file. I run this command:

```
    babel src/app.js --out-file=public/scripts/app.js --presets=env,react --watch
    live-server
```

package.json

```
    {
     "name": "indecision-app",
     "version": "1.0.0",
     "main": "index.js",
     "author": "John",
     "license": "MIT",
     "dependencies": {
       "babel-preset-env": "1.5.2",
       "babel-preset-react": "6.24.1"
     }
   }
```

JSX FILE... src/app.js

```
 // JSX - JavaScript XML
 var template = <div><h1>Indecision App</h1></div>;
 var appRoot = document.getElementById('app');

 ReactDOM.render(template, appRoot);
```

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Indecision App</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Try to add `type="text/babel"` to script tag.

Comment: I typed  <script type="text/babel" src="scripts/app.js"></script> but this made the script text no appear at all. I remove the type="text/babel" and it re-appears.

Comment: Have you installed babel globally?

Comment: I did using Yarn global

Comment: Check this - https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html